# Mocha test complains about unhandled promise but using async/await with catch block

Tags: javascript, async-await, mocha.js

I am using async/await a lot these days but I have a mocha test in which I am testing to ensure that an error is indeed thrown. Below you can see the try/catch block I have to capture this error. The green and grey squares are inserted by Wallaby (a real-time testing tool) and indicate that the catch block is never reached.

[image]

When I run mocha from the command line I get the following message:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FireModel::WrongRelationshipType: Can not use property "employer" on fancyperson with addToRelationship() because it is not a hasMany relationship [ relType: ownedBy, inverse: undefined ]. If you are working with a ownedBy relationship then you should instead use setRelationship() and clearRelationship().

the first line of the `addToRelationship()` checks to see if the relationship type is correct (it is not) and throws the error:

[image]

The `_errorIfNotHasManyReln` method is rather unexciting but for completeness, here it is:

```
protected _errorIfNotHasManyReln(
  property: Extract<keyof T, string>,
  fn: string
) {
  if (this.META.property(property).relType !== "hasMany") {
    const e = new Error(
      `Can not use property "${property}" on ${
        this.modelName
      } with ${fn}() because it is not a hasMany relationship [ relType: ${
        this.META.property(property).relType
      }, inverse: ${
        this.META.property(property).inverse
      } ]. If you are working with a ownedBy relationship then you should instead use setRelationship() and clearRelationship().`
    );
    e.name = "FireModel::WrongRelationshipType";
    throw e;
  }
```

Can someone help me identify why this error isn't being trapped? In desperation I added another try/catch block around the calling of call to `_errorIfNotHasManyreln` and it DOES catch the error but then I try and re-throw it and end up in the same situation again.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function You're not awaiting the promise resolution, so it is continuing beyond your catch block and eventually not being handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your addToRelationship method is also async. You have to `await` the promise response as well :

```
try {
    await bob.addToRelationship("employer", "4567");
}
catch(e) {
    [...]
}
```

If not delayed until the promise rejects then the try/catch didn't receive anything synced and terminated. Then the exception occurs which was obviously not caught.

Comment: Doh! that was it. once you've convinced yourself the world is crazy you stop seeing things. Thanks for bringing sense back to the world for me. :)